# HowTo: Get Durandal (or Backbone) router history and pass to window.someGlobalVar?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, durandal, hottowel, durandal-2.0

I am trying to expand this handy, but basic feedback widget:
http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/

That lives in the window namespace and POSTs to a blob server. I would like to be able to look into the router history of my Durandal app and send a snapshot back with my regular feedack object.

Can anyone advise on how this could be done?

note: since the Durandal 2.0 router is similar to Backbone.js, suggestions from Backbone devs might also be helpful.

I'm thinking of something like this:

`durandalRouter.on('router:navigation:composition-complete')
    .then((instance: string, instruction: DurandalRouteInstruction, router: DurandalRouter) => {
        // todo:  track history... 
});`

Answer (score 1):

You've basically got the answer. You would instantiate an array, preferably as a module, but alternatively as a global variable:

```
window.appHistory = [];
```

Then. you would set up event listening on your router that appends the instruction argument to the history.

```
router.on('router:navigation:complete')
    .then(function(instance, instruction, router) => {
        appHistory.push(JSON.stringify(instruction));
    };
```

The instruction object looks something like this.

```
{
    "fragment": "",
    "queryString": null,
    "config": {
        "title": "Home",
        "route": "",
        "moduleId": "viewmodels/home",
        "hash": "#",
        "routePattern": {}
    },
    "params": [],
    "queryParams": null
}
```